# Get DNS Suffix Search list on remote servers

Tags: powershell, dns

I have a bunch of server that I need to check among other things, if the DNS Suffix list is set up correctly.

I was planning on using PowerShell and the `Get-DnsClientGlobalSetting`, but I can only get to work on my local machine.

So, is there a way, I can get this information from a list of remote servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/get-dnsclientglobalsetting) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> Get-DnsClientGlobalSetting
>    [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
>    [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
>    [-AsJob]
>    [<CommonParameters>]
> ```
>
> [...]
>   `-CimSession`
>   Runs the cmdlet in a remote session or on a remote computer. ***Enter a computer name*** or a session object, such as the output of a `New-CimSession` or `Get-CimSession` cmdlet. The default is the current session on the local computer.

The parameter `-CimSession` takes a list of hostnames (or existing CIM sessions), so invoke it like this:

```
Get-DnsClientGlobalSetting -CimSession 'host1', 'host2', ...
```

Comment: So that was what CimSession was, kind of embarrassing, but thanks for enlightening me